# Finding RefCt issue with view controller not calling dealloc with Instruments

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, instruments

I am trying to use instruments to discover why my View Controller does not call dealloc when popped from the navigation controller. In reviewing the allocations, I found that when I popped my view controller, it keeps a RefCt of 2. I tried to go through all of the retain<->release messages and I did find one group of allocations that seemed out of whack. There are 30 of these messages and there are 16 retain and 14 release. Is this my issue? What are these calls even doing? I am assuming I am retaining self in a block somewhere..?

```
Retain  __copy_helper_block_335
Retain  __copy_helper_block_361
Retain  __copy_helper_block_391
Retain  __copy_helper_block_387
Retain  __copy_helper_block_91
Retain  __copy_helper_block_84
Retain  __copy_helper_block_1797
Retain  __copy_helper_block_2139
Retain  __copy_helper_block_2143
Retain  __copy_helper_block_1647
Retain  __copy_helper_block_2139
Retain  __copy_helper_block_2143
Retain  __copy_helper_block_1678
Retain  __copy_helper_block_2139
Retain  __copy_helper_block_2143
Retain  __copy_helper_block_57
Release __destroy_helper_block_392
Release __destroy_helper_block_336
Release __destroy_helper_block_388
Release __destroy_helper_block_92
Release __destroy_helper_block_85
Release __destroy_helper_block_2140
Release __destroy_helper_block_2144
Release __destroy_helper_block_1648
Release __destroy_helper_block_2140
Release __destroy_helper_block_2144
Release __destroy_helper_block_1679
Release __destroy_helper_block_2140
Release __destroy_helper_block_2144
Release __destroy_helper_block_58
```

I have read through many other questions regarding view controllers not calling dealloc and still am having trouble getting my RefCt to 0. Made sure all of my delegates were weak and pounded through all of the blocks to ensure I wasn't retaining self in a block. There are, however, some places where I use self instead of __weak ([GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker].inviteHandler = ^(GKInvite *acceptedInvite, NSArray *playersToInvite) for example). Do I need to use weakSelf here?

```
- (void) setupInvitationHandler {
    [GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker].inviteHandler = ^(GKInvite *acceptedInvite, NSArray *playersToInvite) {

        ( ... )

        GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithInvite:acceptedInvite];
        mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        [self presentViewController:mmvc animated:YES completion:^{
            [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        }];
    }];
}
```

Comment: So, I was running this test on the Simulator. When I run on my device I do not have the mismatched retain/release issue. Do I not need to worry about this then?